# Working on old Windows Forms project using newer Visual Studio version causes changes to ResX and generated code files. Why?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, version, resx, generated-code

I have been working on a .NET 2.0 Windows Forms project. I am not sure when it was last maintained, and what Development Environment was being used. I think Visual Studio 2005 is likely; the project has probably since been upgraded to Visual Studio 2010/2012 format as part of an overall solution upgrade.

Regardless, I am now working on it using Visual Studio 2012. I noticed, when checking what I was about to commit to source control, that there are a number of changes:

- The '.resx' files are now using version 2.0 of the ResX Schema, rather than version 1.3.
- Some of the generated Forms code is different, e.g.

  `private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;`

  has been replaced with:

  `private IContainer components;`

I've not changed the target framework; it is still targetting .NET 2.0 as I think it always has been.

So, why is this? And, perhaps more importantly, what is the impact? The software will be redeployed to machines running Windows Vista or Windows 7, all of which will have .NET 2.0 installed (at least).